# Unable to install curl command in kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, docker, curl, apt-get

I am using the below command to install curl in one of the pods:

```
$ apt-get install curl
```

But , I am getting below error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

When I am trying to remove the file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

```
$ rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file '/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend'? y
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend': Permission denied
```

I can't use sudo command also :

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Please help, as I am new to Kubernetes and Pods.

Comment: This is most probably the expected behaviour as you aren't supposed to install anything inside containers once they are running. The image from which the container you are trying to install curl on probably contains just the bare minimum required to do its job. Plus, Pods are ephemeral so when they restart, everything (unless persisted) is lost. Why are you installing curl? You may consider changing the image in order to provide it from start if you always need it inside.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @AndD. If you need to have a `curl`, just use an image with it. e.g. I often use this one https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl and it does its job.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is a anti-pattern. Containers are meant to be stateless and not change after they are deployed.

The reason why you can't run `apt-get` is because you are running your container with an unprivileged user as you can tell by the "$" sign in your command prompt. Also `sudo` is not installed and thus not usable.

If you really want to have curl in your container you have a couple of options:

- Extend your docker image, and install `curl` at build time rather than at run time
- Run your container as root and install `curl` from an interactive session as you tried to do (discouraged).

Example of the first approach, the one I suggest you to use, involves a Dockerfile like the following:

```
FROM the-image-name-you-are-currently-using

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y curl
```

You then need to build this new image with (from the same directory where your `Dockerfile` is):

```
docker build -t your-new-image-name:version .
```

After you pushed the image to a registry with `docker push` you can update your `Pod` to use `your-new-image-name:version` as image.

Comment: I am using the Kubernetes pod YAML file, how to achieve this in the YAML file.

Comment: @PixziumMedia why do need to install curl in your container? Any reason why you can't use already existing image with curl? Answer above is not about kubernetes pod, but a correct way to create an image with curl inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to troubleshoot from the container, you can try to leverage bash's built-in TCP/UDP socket support, for example:

```bash
HOSTNAME=google.com; PORT=80
echo >/dev/tcp/$HOSTNAME/$PORT && echo "Open" || echo "Closed"
```

If your pod/container has a programming language installed, Python, Ruby, or Node you can use a single bash line to test as well. Take a look at the different options I prepared here https://go.rebelion.la/uSTroubleshooting